# How do I find value of register and flags in Assembler?

Tags: z80

```
 Programmcode | Zero-Flag | Sign-Flag | Register A | Register HL
              |     0     |     0     |     00h    |    00 00h
--------------|-----------|-----------|------------|------------
MOV HL, 00ffh |           |           |            |
DEC HL        |           |           |            |
ADD 81h       |           |           |            |
CP A          |           |           |            |
SUB 02h       |           |           |            |
```

I have part of program in MC8-Assembler (The CPU of the MC8 is formed by the 8bit processor Zilog Z80 of the Training Board) What value is going to have flag after execution and whatvalue is being found in register? Values before execution are given in first column.

Can someone do it + write an explanation?

Comment: what have you done so far besides this question?

Answer (score 2):

What Intel calls `MOV`, Zilog calls `LD`; otherwise you can work out the answer by looking at e.g. [this instruction table](http://clrhome.org/table/).

`MOV HL, 00ffh` is `LD HL, 00ffh` in Zilog terms, so look up the appropriate `LD HL`. It's instruction 0x21 and it tells you that it loads the value into HL and doesn't affect any flags. So that's row one sorted. `DEC HL` over at 0x2b also doesn't affect any flags (which almost always catches me out, for the record) but `ADD A,*` does so that's where sign and zero might change, depending on what you think happens to A.

Just look up each instruction in turn, see what it does, do that thing, then consider what the flags will be if that's an instruction that affects the flags.